# How to find the indeces of the columns with at least k non-zero element on it?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A as follows:

```
A =

     1     2     0     0     4
     0     0     0     1     3
     0     0     1     1     1
```

I would like to find the indecies of column A where each column has more than k-nonero elements.
I used:

```
find(all(A~=0));
```

but it returns the index of the columns where there exist at least one non-zero element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking where *all* the values in a row are non-zero, rather count how many are and then apply your threshold:

```
k = 3
find(sum(A~=0,2)>=k)
```

returns:

```
ans =

   1
   3
```

Answer (score 2):

It might help you if you take it step by step.
First, find the number of nonzero elements in each column:

```
nNonZero = sum(A~=0)
```

Then find the columns that are more than k

```
find(nNonZero>k)
```